# Is it allowed to insert a null value into a C++ std::map?

Tags: c++, std, stdmap

I'm considering a checkerboard design, and would like to do something along the lines of:

```
typedef std::map <std::string, CheckerPiece> MapType;
MapType CheckerBoard;

CheckerBoard.insert({"a1", null});
```

Is this allowed, or is there a way to do something similar?  The idea is that I want to maintain a board state, while moving CheckerPiece objects from one location to another.

*Edit:*
Along the same lines, is it possible to do the following:

```
CheckerBoard.insert({"a1", new CheckerPiece()});
```

Comment: Do you want a map of strings to pointers instead?

Comment: This is not allowed. As a workaround, you can use a wrapper-type like [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) - this is to be preferred over pointers.

Comment: You should change your design so that you don't need to have NULL entries in the container.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your map doesn't hold `CheckerPiece` pointers, so what you are trying to do won't even compile, unless you have an implicit constructor for `CheckerPrice` that takes a pointer as argument. This is ignoring the fact that `null` doesn't mean anything in `C++`. Assuming you mean `NULL` or `nullptr`, you cannot insert either of those, or the result of

```
new CheckerPiece()
```

into your map, period. The expression above returns a pointer to `CheckerPiece`.

C++ doesn't have a concept of null values for types (unless you specifically engineer one). A workaround is to use a wrapper type that give you optional semantics, i.e. allow you to check whether something has been "set" or not. One example is [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Here's an untested example:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

boost::optional<CheckerPiece> piece;

if (piece) {
  // piece is not set, we should never get here
}

piece.reset(CheckerPiece( constructor arguments...));

if (piece) {
  // piece is set, use it!
  piece.move();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think I might just add a CheckerPiece to every element and create a member bool isActive to switch them on and off. I'd rather not get too complex on this - unless you could provide a quick example using the boost library?

Comment: @ctote I added an example. I haven't tested it, there may be syntax errors but the general principle is OK.

Answer (score 1):

What does `CheckerPiece` look like?  The most obvious solution
would be to add an additional possibility corresponding to the
absence of a piece.  Pieces really don't have any behavior, and
you don't need them as such; you really only need the
information as to the state of a square: which is red, black or
empty, and crowned or not (which is ignored if empty).

I might add that keeping a checker board as a map is perhaps not
the most astucious solution either.  I'd go with something like:

```
CheckerPiece board[10][10];
```

(or `CheckerPiece board[N][N]`, where `N` is a template
argument, if you want to support local variants, and not just
the international standard checkers).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define your map to use a `CheckerPiece*` instead of a `CheckerPiece` if you want to use pointers/heap allocated CheckerPieces. There is no such thing as `null` in C++ as a "there is no object here" value. The canonical way to indicate an optional object without using a third party library is to use a pointer and set it to `nullptr` if the optional element isn't present.

I would probably use `boost::optional` to indicate that the CheckerPiece might or might not be in a given location unless there is a reason why you can't use a third-party library.

Comment: There's no real reason I can't use third-party, but I'd rather avoid it for this simple case. Are you saying that I could potentially do something along the lines of:

typedef std::map <std::string, CheckerPiece*> MapType;
MapType CheckerBoard;

CheckerBoard.insert({"a1", nullptr});

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Change your definition of Board.

A board or board state is a collection of `<checker piece, location>`.  Any board position that is not in this container is considered empty.  Any checker that is not in the board state has been captured.

With this concept, there is no need for a null checker piece and no need to compare a checker piece for NULL.

When planning moves or creating a move history, you can use a container of board states.

I suggest creating function that will draw the board using a given board state.  This frees up the problem of trying to represent the actual board on each move from the board state container.